# Number of Atoms

Tags: atomic-physics

I have some confusion regarding the past paper solutions, on atomic physics.

So in my past paper solutions it states that the number of atoms in $1$kg of carbon is given by  $=\frac{12\times 1000}{N_A}$, but if I remember correctly the number of atoms is equal to the number of moles times the Avogadro's number and hence should be  $=\frac{1000\times N_A}{12}?$ It does a similar thing for the number of atoms in 1 kg of Uranium - 235, which is given to be in the solution  $=\frac{235\times 1000}{N_A}$, and not  $=\frac{1000 \times N_A}{235}$

So I was wondering which is the correct answer? I would appreciate some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
n_{moles} = 1000 gm/ (12 gm/mole)
$$
so
$$
n_{atom}= 1000 \times N_A/12
$$

Comment: Yes I made a typo and fixed my post. So does this imply the past paper solutions are wrong?

Comment: @aurora-borealis. Yes. I think they are wrong -- but I was never much good at chemistry.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification. I am trying to teach A - level Physics and these past paper solutions sometimes confuse my already shady high school physics and chemistry.